# Doxygen cannot parsing the structure documentation in the source file

Tags: latex, documentation, doxygen, tex, pdflatex

Doxygen cannot parsing a structure documentation inside .c file(and cannot create a corresponding .tex file) but parsing correctly from a separate .h file

Assumptions: Does the structures inside .c file where generally the functions are documented are not visible to doxygen parser?

Workflow: doxygen run >parsing from files>create a pdf
The final generated file is missing the structure documentation inside .c file but all other structures inside a separate .h files are documented and find their place in generated .pdf file

Why missing?

What I tried: I have tried giving those structure names (which I thought missing in the documentation) in the .tex file automated part as \input{structt_Ref2_Control} then I am getting an omake error saying:

> "The .tex (relevant for missing structure) file is missing"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Then, present us a clear description of what are you trying to do, what you got wrong and what you expected to get, along with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The minimal working example should just contain the minimal to reproduce the problem, should contain the doxygen settings different from the default settings. It should also contain the doxygen version used (in your case 1.8.11)

Comment: formatting to be more readable.